# Should I publish book chapters as standalone articles before approaching a publisher?

Tags: publications, journals, books, publishers

[Humanities - Post Doc Stage] Do you encourage the publication of chapters as articles prior to full book publication, with the aim to improve research profile? Or do you advise publishing a book of previously unpublished work? Or do you suggest publishing some and retaining other research? Please detail any experience of this in your response, with reference to approaching publishers if possible.

Comment: Some publishers won't republish existing work. And it is up to the publisher whether to publish something or not. Find a publisher and work with them.

Comment: As I understand it, in certain branches of the Humanities, typically the first publication is a book based on the thesis.  You are (if lucky) hired to an academic position, you work hard preparing your thesis for publication, and then that publication is the basis for promotion.  That was years ago.  Nowadays perhaps that "academic position" may be a postdoc, and that "promotion" may be a regular teaching position.

Answer (score 1):

Publishers are going to look at your background before agreeing to a publish your work. Things looked at include:

- Your citation metrics
- Reviewers for your publication proposal
- Your CV

Publishing some standalone articles will certainly improve all three, but you'd have less material when it actually comes time to publish a book (because the same material typically cannot be reused). So the question effectively becomes, "can I publish now or do I need a better profile?". Only you can answer that question, unfortunately.

If you don't know the answer either I'd suggest contacting a publisher now, and if they reject your proposals, then publish standalone articles first.